# How to style rotated TextBlocks closer together?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I manually set these TextBlocks up I was able to space them out nicely by altering the left margin to -50, except for the first one which got set to 0(zero).
[image]

I am now get the TextBlocks populated through binding, so when I apply a style it happens to all TextBlocks.

```
<Style x:Key="RotatedText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-45" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-50,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
```

Now this happens:
[image]

What I am wondering is how can I create either a style that works for all TextBlocks or define a separate style for the first TextBlock and another for the rest.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstModules" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Modules}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" CanVerticallyScroll="False" CanHorizontallyScroll="False"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemRotatedText}" Text="{Binding ModuleName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I just tried what I thought would be a decent solution to this: translate transform by -90 then render transform by 45 with a render transform origin set to 0,1. However, WPF is clipping for some reason, even with `ClipToBounds=false` on everything.

Comment: I noticed that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just move the whole `ListBox` by giving it a left margin of 50. This way all the `TextBlock`s that are contained in the `ListBox` will get shifted as desired.

Comment: This pushes it over but it is still clipping the front of the ListBox

Comment: @Hank I suspected that might happen. Your Converter approach seems like the way to go. Although, I suppose you could make it more generic by using the `AlternationIndex` of the `ListBox` to selectively apply the Margin only to items having index > 0. This way your converter will work for other object types as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using an IValueConverter to analyze the item to see if it is the first item in the list.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModuleName, Converter={StaticResource firstItemConvertion}}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-60,0,0,0" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>


public class FirstItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object obj, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int.Parse((string)parameter)) < ModuleRepository.GetModuleIndexByModuleName(((string)obj));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object obj, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```